# core-js errors on vue build

Tags: vue.js, npm, babeljs, core-js

I have a problem to build a specific package with `npm run build` -> `vue build`.
The author of the repository seems to be too busy to help me and I have already gone through any online resource and tried so much.

The error is apparently related to `core-js`. I don't know where it is related to, I assume babel?

I have even containerized the process to be sure about every dependency.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:lts-alpine # I also tried node, node:10 and node:8

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install -g @vue/cli @vue/cli-service-global
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "build"]
```

**Cloned repository (master):**
https://github.com/lusaxweb/vuesax

**Main error message:**

```
These dependencies were not found:

* core-js/library/fn/array/from in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/core-js/array/from.js
* core-js/library/fn/array/is-array in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/core-js/array/is-array.js
* core-js/library/fn/get-iterator in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/core-js/get-iterator.js
* core-js/library/fn/is-iterable in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/core-js/is-iterable.js
* core-js/library/fn/object/define-property in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/core-js/object/define-property.js
* core-js/library/fn/promise in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/core-js/promise.js
* core-js/library/fn/symbol in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/core-js/symbol.js
* core-js/library/fn/symbol/iterator in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/core-js/symbol/iterator.js
* core-js/modules/es6.array.find in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsDropDown/vsDropDownMenu.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
* core-js/modules/es6.array.from in ./src/functions/vsLoading/index.js
* core-js/modules/es6.array.iterator in ./src/index.js, /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsButton/vsButton.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& and 11 others
* core-js/modules/es6.array.sort in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsTable/vsTh.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&, /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsTable/vsTable.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
* core-js/modules/es6.function.name in ./src/components/vsAlert/index.js, ./src/components/vsAvatar/index.js and 33 others
* core-js/modules/es6.math.sign in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsSlider/vsSlider.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&, /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsTooltip/vsTooltip.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
* core-js/modules/es6.math.trunc in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsUpload/vsUpload.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
* core-js/modules/es6.number.constructor in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsAvatar/vsAvatar.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&, /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsCheckBox/vsCheckBox.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& and 17 others
* core-js/modules/es6.object.keys in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsButton/vsButton.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&, /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsDropDown/vsDropDown.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& and 9 others
* core-js/modules/es6.regexp.constructor in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsSelect/vsSelectItem.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
* core-js/modules/es6.regexp.replace in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsSelect/vsSelect.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&, /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsSelect/vsSelectItem.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& and 4 others
* core-js/modules/es6.regexp.search in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsTable/vsTable.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&, /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/functions/vsNotifications/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& and 1 other
* core-js/modules/es6.regexp.split in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsAvatar/vsAvatar.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&, /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsSelect/vsSelect.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& and 3 others
* core-js/modules/es6.regexp.to-string in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsInputNumber/vsInputNumber.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&, /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsTable/vsTable.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
* core-js/modules/es6.string.fixed in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/functions/vsNotifications/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
* core-js/modules/es6.string.includes in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsCheckBox/vsCheckBox.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&, /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsIcon/vsIcon.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& and 4 others
* core-js/modules/es6.string.iterator in ./src/functions/vsLoading/index.js
* core-js/modules/es7.array.includes in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsCheckBox/vsCheckBox.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&, /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsIcon/vsIcon.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& and 5 others
* core-js/modules/es7.object.get-own-property-descriptors in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsButton/vsButton.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&, /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsDropDown/vsDropDown.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& and 8 others
* core-js/modules/es7.object.values in ./src/index.js, /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsTable/vsTable.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& and 1 other
* core-js/modules/web.dom.iterable in ./src/index.js, /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-1!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/vsAvatar/vsAvatar.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& and 15 others
```

**Full Log (docker run starting at line 132):**
https://hastebin.com/adimexubow

Any hints are very appreciated! I'm really desperate with this error. All I want is to get this project built.

Comment: Did you find how to fix this ?

Comment: @QuentinDel The repository author fixed the bug. I don't know what exactly fixed it, but you can check through the commits from Feb 5th and Feb 6th (https://github.com/lusaxweb/vuesax/commits/master)